# Differentiability: unequal limits imply non-existence of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If left- and right-hand limits $\lim_{x\to x_0-}f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0+}f'(x)$ exist but $\lim_{x\to x_0-}f'(x)\neq \lim_{x\to x_0+}f'(x)$
why does this imply that $f'(x_0) $ does not exist and, therefore, $f$ is not differentiable in $x_0$?

Answer (score 2):

The following useful result is is a consequence — perhaps not too well-known — of the Mean Value Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $\{x:|x-x_0)|<r\}$ and differentiable on $\{x:0<|x-x_0|<r\}$ (for some positive $r$) and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$ exists and equals $\ell$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)=\ell$.

Indeed, the proof shows a bit more: If $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+} f'(x)=\ell$, then the right-hand derivative $f'_+(x_0)=\ell$. So, if $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+} f'(x)=\ell$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f'(x)=\mathscr m$, then $f'_+(x_0)=\ell$ and $f'_-(x_0)=\mathscr m$. $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if $\ell=\mathscr m$.

The proof goes like this: For $0<x-x_0<r$, we deduce from the Mean Value Theorem that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(c_x) \quad\text{for some } x_0<c_x<x.$$
As $x\to x_0^+$, $c_x$ is squeezed to approach $x_0$, and so
$$f'_+(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{\xi\to x_0^+} f'(\xi) = \ell.$$
(You can make this as rigorous as you wish with a standard $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument.) I leave the left-hand limit to you.

Comment: Thank you! Why can you apply the Mean Value Theorem? $f$ is not defined on an closed interval but on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is the closed interval on which I’m applying it in this argument?

Comment: Isn't this a requirement in the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Sure. I’m asking you to figure it out from what I said and answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

suppose that derivative of f(x) exists :

our assumptions are that derivative right and left exist and are equal to g(L) and g(R):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0-} f'(x) = g(L)  -> then: -\delta<x-x_0<0 \implies |f'(x)-g(L)|<\epsilon$
and
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0+} f'(x) = g(R)   -> then: 0<x-x_0<\delta \implies |f'(x)-g(R)|<\epsilon$

and that g(L) is not equal to g(R)

if limit for derivative exists then the proposition below is true:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x) = g(x_0)  -> then: 0<|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f'(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$

then by the proposition above the propositions below :
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0-} f'(x) = g(x_0)  -> then: -\delta<x-x_0<0 \implies |f'(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$
and
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0+} f'(x) = g(x_0)   -> then: 0<x-x_0<\delta \implies |f'(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$
are true but by the uniqueness of limits it would imply that

g(L) = g(R)=$g(x_0)$ then we have a contracdiction

Comment: $f$ can be differentiable at $x_0$ without being continuously differentiable at $x_0$ (examples are standard). So showing that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$ fails to exist does *not* imply that $f'(x_0)$ fails to exist.

Comment: thank you for correcting my mistake sir, could you provide some examples? is there any general condition that implies the existence of derivative but not the continuity of it? is there any other way to prove the theorem other than MVT ?

Comment: You need either MVT or Darboux's Theorem (whose proof requires the Maximum/Minimum Value Theorem on closed intervals). The standard example of a differentiable function whose derivative is not continuous is $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x), & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof by contradiction.  Suppose $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $x_0$.
[Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) states that derivatives have the intermediate value property: if $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $[a,b]$ and $y$ is between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then there is some $c \in (a,b)$ where $f'(c) = y$.

Now suppose $\lim_{x \to x_0-} f'(x) = y_1$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0+} f'(x) = y_2 \ne y_1$.
For convenience let's say $y_1 < y_2$ (the argument when $y_2 < y_1$ is similar).
Take  $\delta > 0$ so $|f'(x) - y_1| < (y_2 - y_1)/3$ for $x_0 - \delta < x < x_0$ and $|f'(x) - y_2| < (y_2 - y_1)/3$ for $x_0 < x < \delta <x_0 + \delta$.

If $y_1 + (y_2-y_1)/3  < y < y_2 - (y_2 - y_1)/3$, then $y$ is between $f(x_1)$ for  $x_1 \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0)$ and $f(x_2)$ for $x_2 \in (x_0, x_0 + \delta)$, but $x$ for which $f(x) = y$ can't be in either $(x_0 - \delta, x_0)$ or $(x_0, x_0 + \delta)$.  That leaves only $x_0$ itself, but that can take care of only one out of an  interval of possible $y$ values.